# I can't install hydro on Ubuntu quantal

Tags: ros, apt, ros-hydro, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i type the apt-get install command, i get ,

sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-hydro-desktop-full : Depends: ros-hydro-desktop but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-hydro-perception but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-hydro-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167586/i-can%27t-install-hydro-on-ubuntu-quantal./) by [amartya18x](https://answers.ros.org/users/18216/amartya18x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have the universe and metaverse repositories enabled?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0